# Aside China, is there another country whose constitution forbids foreign meddling?

Tags: china, constitution, international

> China consistently opposes imperialism, hegemonism and colonialism,
> works to strengthen its solidarity with the people of all other
> countries, supports oppressed peoples and other developing countries
> in their just struggles **to win and safeguard their independence and
> develop their economies, and strives to safeguard world peace and
> promote the cause of human progress.**
>
> The achievements of China's revolution, development and reform would
> have been impossible without the support of the world's people. The
> future of China is closely bound up with the future of the world.
> **China pursues an independent foreign policy, observes the five
> principles of mutual respect for sovereignty and territorial
> integrity, mutual nonaggression, mutual noninterference in internal
> affairs, equality and mutual benefit, and peaceful coexistence, keeps
> to a path of peaceful development, follows a mutually beneficial
> strategy of opening up, works to develop diplomatic relations and
> economic and cultural exchanges with other countries, and promotes the
> building of a human community with a shared future.** China
> consistently opposes imperialism, hegemonism and colonialism, works to
> strengthen its solidarity with the people of all other countries,
> supports oppressed peoples and other developing countries in their
> just struggles to win and safeguard their independence and develop
> their economies, and strives to safeguard world peace and promote the
> cause of human progress.

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China

Aside China, is there another country whose constitution forbids foreign meddling? I am not asking if what they claim is true, but I am asking if there's any other country that also has forbids foreign interference in its constitution like China does. It seems odd to add something like that in the constitution when the constitution is usually intended on protecting the interest of its citizens.

Comment: The quote doesn't prohibit **all** kinds of "foreign meddling". Only specific ones, not aligned with China's worldview, like imperialism. Promoting communist revolutions abroad is not a prohibition that can be read in that quote (before the edit--I'll have to read the larger one now).

Comment: @Fizz - Right, arguably China's constitution is unusual in that it actually *requires* certain kinds of meddling, namely supporting oppressed peoples in their struggles for independence and safeguarding world peace.

Comment: The 2nd para added in the edit talking of "mutual noninterference in internal affairs" is more or less from the UN charter. I don't expect countries that have much older Constitutions than that to have included it. The principle only started to be affirmed after WW2.

Comment: @Obie2.0: which also makes the two paras slightly contradictory.

Comment: Well, imperialism is when other countries do it. When China does it, it's supporting Freedom. The USA government will also tell you that it only wants to support human rights in other countries and that it's Russia and China that want to dominate the world.

Comment: i don't know what do you mean under constitution "forbids foreign meddling", but Russian constitution modified in 2020 year has some amendments that protect Russia sovereign territory boards, russian(русский) language and russian nation culture aspects. Also there is a Federal Law that prohibit to govt clercs and judges to be owners of the second(foreign) citizenship. Also there is no  translation of the new constitution to the english language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IRAN (Islamic Republic of)** (Alternative source: [Islamic Republic of Iran Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://en.mfa.ir/portal/viewpage/3997/constitution))

> **[Article 152](https://www.wipo.int/edocs/lexdocs/laws/en/ir/ir001en.pdf):** The foreign policy of the Islamic Republic of Iran is based on the rejection of any
> kind of domination, both its exercise and submission to it; the preservation of the all-inclusive
> independence of the country and its territorial integrity; the defense of the rights of all Muslims;
> non-alignment in relation to the domineering powers; mutual peaceful relations with nonaggressive states.